# How to subset a data frame based on categorical variables when a row can be defined by more than categorical variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large data frame and I would like to remove all entries that contain certain categorical variables. The data frame is such that a row entry can have more than one categorical variable assigned to it. In this simplified example:

```
x<-(1:10)
y<-c("a,b","c,d","c","c","a","a,d","b,d","c","c","a")
example_df <- data.frame(x,y)
example_df
```

Note that row entry 1 is defined as being both "a" and "b" separated by a comma, while row 5 is defined as "a". How could one, for example, command R to return a new data frame containing only the rows that do not contain "a" for column "y"?

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr and stringr

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
example_df %>% filter(!str_detect(y,'a'))
  x   y
1 2 c,d
2 3   c
3 4   c
4 7 b,d
5 8   c
6 9   c
```

Comment: Thank you. How might I extend this to to more than one element at a time, say, I wanted to filter out 'a' and 'b' simultaneously?

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet, you can use example_df %>% filter(!str_detect(y,'a|b')), so we basically saying filter out 'a' or 'b'. You can also use this construct: example_df %>% filter(!str_detect(y,'[ab]'))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grepl` to do pattern matching and return rows that do not have 'a' in them.

```
subset(example_df, !grepl('a', y))

#  x   y
#2 2 c,d
#3 3   c
#4 4   c
#7 7 b,d
#8 8   c
#9 9   c
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
subset(example_df, setdiff(seq_len(nrow(example_df)), grep('a', y)))
```